# How to use if statement in ntplib real-time in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider the code below:

```
def set_ntp_time():
    times = []

    for address in ntp_addresses:
        ntp_client = ntplib.NTPClient()
        ntp_response = ntp_client.request(address, version=3)
        ntp_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(ntp_response.orig_time)
        fomatted_time = ntp_time.strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f")
        
        times.append(fomatted_time)
    
    global time
    time = min(times)

set_ntp_time()

print(time)
```

It prints some hours in milliseconds like :

```
21:02:23.2898
```

I should run a function at for example (08:30:00) o'clock.
So my question is when I run the script it just get the times once but how should I write it in order to the script wait until the closest time to 08:30:00 and then run the function?

I used `schedule` module but it's not accurate. So give me other responses please.

Something like this:

```
if (time === '08:30:00'):
    ...
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not accurate"? What accuracy do you need? Seconds, Milliseconds, Microseconds? If `schedule` can't do it good enough, why would anyone else be able to do a better job? Have you tried [apscheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)?

Comment: @ThomasWeller And consider that using something like `while` loop has a big load on the script.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Something like `datetime.datetime.now().time() >= '08:30:00'`. But instead of `datetime` I want to use my variable `time` which has NTP time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, the approach is straight forward:

1. Get the NTP time (I'll call it `now`)
2. Define the time you want to run the code (`runat`)
3. Calculate the difference
4. Sleep for that time
5. Do whatever you want at that time

Note that asking NTP servers for the time will itself take some time. So if you print the NTP time as part of the step 5, it will always appear late. I'll use the local time to compensate for that in the code below.

```
from time import sleep
import ntplib
from datetime import datetime


def get_ntp_time() -> datetime:
    ntp_pool = ['0.pool.ntp.org', 'uk.pool.ntp.org', 'ie.pool.ntp.org']
    for item in ntp_pool:
        call = ntplib.NTPClient()
        response = call.request(item, version=3)
        try:
            t = datetime.fromtimestamp(response.orig_time)
            return t  # Use the time of the first NTP server that returns a time
        except:  # no response from server
            pass


now = get_ntp_time()
runat = datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day, now.hour, now.minute + 1, 0)  # Arbitrary, put 8:30 here
print("NTP time:", now)
print("Time to wait:", runat - now)
sleep((runat - now).total_seconds())

localbefore = datetime.now()
print("Running the job ...")
now = get_ntp_time()
localafter = datetime.now()
print("NTP time:", now)
print("Job ran at: ", now - (localafter - localbefore))
```

Example output:

```
NTP time: 2021-01-05 15:43:21.772182
Time to wait: 0:00:38.227818
Running the job ...
NTP time: 2021-01-05 15:44:00.031360
Job ran at:  2021-01-05 15:44:00.010784
```

You'll probably not get much closer than 17 ms, since thread scheduling on Windows happens at 1/64th of a second.

> ```
> time = min(times)
> ```

That's not gonna work. The minimum time is too long ago. If you ask all servers for the time in a loop, time passes by. If you ask all three servers, you need to take the maximum time.